# Connect domain (from Namecheap) to hosting (at OVH)

Tags: networking, dns, website, domain, web-hosting

I've got hosting from OVH and bought a domain from Namecheap. I want to connect the domain to a website hosted at OVH but the customer support at both companies sucks and can't provide the info that would make it work. I found some tutorials online that said I just need to copy all the nameservers' addresses from the hosting provider and paste them in the nameserver fields at the domain registrar.

The nameservers as displayed at OVH hosting:

[image]

Pasted at the registrar:

[image]

This unfortunately doesn't work. When I type my domain the browser says "This site can't be reached". What did I do wrong?

[image]

Comment: Give it some time to work. DNS records are cached, making a DNS change is not instant.

Comment: I waited several *hours* before posting here.

Comment: It can take up to 72 hours for DNS changes to propagate across the Internet. What result do you get if you run `nslookup -type=soa <your domain>` in a terminal/command prompt?

Comment: Server:         8.8.8.8
Address:        8.8.8.8#53

Non-authoritative answer:
<the domain>
        origin = dns17.ovh.net
        mail addr = tech.ovh.net
        serial = 2018012803
        refresh = 86400
        retry = 3600
        expire = 3600000
        minimum = 300

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it turns out it wasn't because of slow propagation. I had to reset my DNS zone at OVH (choosing simplified default setup) and then adding an A record pointing to the web server's IP address.

All the records seem to look the same as before the reset but I guess there must be some settings which are not displayed in the admin panel that changed and it's working now.

Too bad, OVH customer support is so terrible that I waited a week for them to help with it and then finally fixed it myself.